# Subdomain URL to Remain Same In Address Bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, subdomain, cpanel

i have created a subdomain in cpanel like

> test.domain.com

, and when i hit the URL, it goes to

> domain.com/test

and shows the same in the URL in address bar like domain.com/test/.
.
Secondly a page named e.g. pagetest in this test domain shows as

> domain.com/test/pagetest.php

.

what i need is that this url should remain same in address bar like test.domain.com and the page should display like this in address bar e.g.

> **test.domain.com**
>   **test.domain.com/pagetest.php**

.

How Can I Do This?

Comment: It sounds like your web server is automatically redirecting from ``test.domain.com`` to ``domain.com/test``. What's the contents of ``.htaccess``?

Comment: i havn't added anything to .htaccess, i am using cpannel only to create subdomain. but i have access to it and can update it if any required

Comment: @kmoser please guide me about it

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a shared hosting plan somewhere? In that case the redirect may be beyond your control, e.g. an ``httpd.conf`` or ``vhosts`` setting. I suggest you contact your hosting provider for assistance.